# QUERY for JOIN a @JoinTable in a @ManyToMany relationship with the non-owned table, in eclipselink jpa

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, inner-join

**The own class with the @JoinTable ("commit_reference_issue"), I need make a join with this table called "commit_reference_issue" and the table "issue" represented by non-own class Issue. The join that I need is show after the class Issue.**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="commit")
@NamedQuery(name="Commit.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Commit c")
public class Commit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="sha", nullable=false, length=45)
private String sha;

//code omitted...

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Issue
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="commit_reference_issue",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="commit_sha", nullable=false, referencedColumnName = "sha")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name = "issue_number", referencedColumnName = "number"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "issue_repository_id_git", referencedColumnName = "repository_id_git")
    }
)
private List<Issue> issues;
//code omitted...
```

The non-own class Issue

```
@Entity
@Table(name="issue")
@IdClass(IssuePK.class)
@NamedQuery(name="Issue.findAll", query="SELECT i FROM Issue i")
public class Issue implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "number")
private int number;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "repository_id_git", referencedColumnName = "id_git")
private Repository repository;

//code omitted...

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Commit
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="issues")
private List<Commit> commits;

//code omitted...
```

How can I translate this query below to query in jpa eclipselink?

```sql
SELECT i.* FROM issue i INNER JOIN commit_reference_issue cri
ON i.number = cri.issue_number AND 
i.repository_id_git = cri.issue_repository_id_git;
```

Comment: You can't get this SQL exactly, but you can get the same results using JPQL "Select i from Issue i join i.commits c"

Comment: Thanks @Chris! This work! I only add a clause where in JPQL, because the database has many repositories. So this JPQL is: "Select i from Issue i join i.commits c where i.repository =:arg1", where "arg1" is the Repository repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Chris! This work! I only add a clause where in JPQL, because the database has many repositories. 
So this JPQL is:

**"Select i from Issue i join i.commits c where i.repository =:arg1"**, where "arg1" is the Repository repository.